# Trying to figure out how a directive works, to design a test for it

Tags: angularjs

I'm using Jasmine+Karma and need to find a way to test an angular directive used to alert the user if passwords don't match - it seems to accomplish this with a directive the renders true or false, and there is  with ngShow on the HTML that displays when this, along with a couple other properties, are true.

Here's the directive. I'm having a little difficulty understanding how it works.

```js
app.directive('passwordMatch', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope:true,
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, control) {
            var checker = function () {
                var e1 = scope.$eval(attrs.ngModel);
                var e2 = scope.$eval(attrs.passwordMatch);
                if(e2!=null)
                return e1 == e2;
            };
            scope.$watch(checker, function (n) {
                control.$setValidity("passwordNoMatch", n);
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

```html
<small class="errorMessage" data-ng-show="signupForm.password2.$dirty && signupForm.password2.$error.passwordNoMatch && !signupForm.password2.$error.required"> Password do not match.</small>
```

So as far as I'm able to tell, what's happening is scope.$watch is watching the checker function for a change, which then gets put into the listeners argument and updates the property on the DOM?

How does it do that, then when the purpose is to detect if passwords do not match - if they don't match, then e1 === e2 is false, and this value is passed into `$scope.watch(checker, function(n)...`? If that was how it worked, then wouldn't it set the of value `passwordNoMatch` to false, which would make ng-show hidden?

Or is that not how it works, it works another way?

And, before that, what's going on with the link: function part?

Where is the scope coming from (it just says `scope:true` in the directive?) 
And the elem? And the `attr` (the attributes from html elements?)?

Is angular just looking through a list of each and every one of them, the elements and attributes, and the scope? Is there a `passwordMatch` property already in there somehow?

What is `$eval` doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of questions here and spending some time with the Angular docs would help you answer a lot of them. I'll put links to the relevant docs so you can get a fuller explanation.

**So as far as I'm able to tell, what's happening is scope.$watch is watching the checker function for a change, which then gets put into the listeners argument and updates the property on the DOM? How does it do that?**

I think you are almost there. When you watch a function it gets called on every digest cycle and if the return value of the function has changed then it calls the function you passed as the second argument i.e.

```
function(n){
    control.$setValidity("passwordNoMatch", n);
}
```

To understand this function you need to understand what the `require` option does. You have set require to 'ngModel' and basically what this means is that the `control` variable passed in as the 4th argument to your link function is a reference to [NgModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController), which provides an API for the ngModel directive.

The `$setValidity("passwordNoMatch", n)` bit sets the value of the property 'passwordNoMatch' on the `$error` object to the value of `n`. So, `n` here is the return value of the function you are watching and the `$error` object is a property of the [FormController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) that is available on all [angular forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form) which have the name attribute defined in the HTML form tag. So, basically this function is what sets the value of the `signupForm.password2.$error.passwordNoMatch` that you see in your `<small>` tag.

**Where is the scope coming from (it just says scope:true in the directive?)**

The scope in link function is (from the [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile))..

> The scope to be used by the directive for registering watches.

The `scope: true` bit is what tells Angular whether to create a new scope for the directive or to create an 'isolate scope' which does not 'prototypically inherit from the parent scope'. I would recommend that you spend some quality time reading about the [directive definition object](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) if you really want to grok directives.

**What is $eval doing?**

The first argument passed to scope.$eval is executed as an [Angular Expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) and the result is returned. So in your code I suspect they will both return strings from your password fields which you then check to see if they match.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I took a look at the docs, but didn't make it around to the 'require' part.

I'm checking them out now - but I'm not able to find anything with `'passwordMatch'` 

Is that just the directive name, being called recursively? Is recursively the correct word here? 

And this still is a little stubborn to wrap my head around - if `(scope.$eval(attrs.ngModel) == scope.$eval(attrs.passwordMatch))` is TRUE, then `control.$setValidity("passwordNoMatch", n)` would set the element "passwords don't match" to be shown. So, what's being tested here? When `e1 != e2`, then the passwords match?

Comment: Oh, I get it - there is a `password-match="signup.password"` on the HTML. 

I didn't see this at first, because `password-match` doesn't look like `passwordMatch` - the name of the directive. But then I learned, angular digests the HTML syntax by removing things like `-` and converting that to camelCase, so `password-match` is referring to the `passwordMatch`  directive.

Thanks for your response, though, it has useful information, so I'll take that answer.

Comment: Yep, take your time with the docs. They are not perfect but there's a lot of information to get across so it's not easy. You just have to keep reading and them and trying stuff out in your code. Good luck.